# You Tube Iframe API quota

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there any limit of Youtube video in Iframe API ?
for example : Daily 1000 Times etc?

Comment: Which limit are you referring to, specifically?

Answer (score 3):

There is no YouTube iFrame Quota. This API doesn't require an API key and their is no mention of limit on it's documentation or developer console