# Youtube API does loadVideoById(videoId) affect quota

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Not sure based on the docs whether the method loadVideoById(videoId) incurs any quota cost.

Would this equal a one quota cost or not?

Also, in this post:

[How to Play a Playlist using YouTube JavaScript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123143/how-to-play-a-playlist-using-youtube-javascript-api)

The first answer by jbx, does this answer require any quota (playing a playlist, no searching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably would not affect your quota, if you are just using [Youtube IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). This would only add up to your quota if you will be using [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) (to get such as videos, playlists, and channels), [Youtube Analytics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/) and [Youtube Reporting.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/)

[image]

These APIs will be needing API Key or OAuth 2.0 client IDs to function ([Credentials, access, security, and identity](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158857?hl=en)).

A related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32893780/5995040) also said, that "**there is no API key needed and no quota limit specified in any documents or developer console.**"

Hope this helps!